# find k such that both part of array is sorted in increasing order

Tags: find

suppose we are given sorted array of n distinct numbers that has been rotated k steps, for some unknown integer k between 1 to n-1. "Rotated means array A is such that the first part of array A[1..K]" is sorted in increasing order, the suffix A[K+1...n] is also sorted in increasing order, but A[n] < A[1]. The problem is to find k.

Comment: What have you tried? This seems like a pretty simple linear scan for the first adjacent pair of elements that meet a certain condition... Also, consider suggesting what language you are talking about - C? C++? Python? Perl? shell? Eiffel? Haskell? OCaml?

Comment: I need only the simple algorithm.